# iPhone ringtones and other sounds on Android

Tags: ios, ringtone

My current phone is an HTC Desire and I was using an iPhone before. I am really liking the ringtons and other system sounds on the iPhone and I am now looking a way to have these on my Android phone. Are there any apps for that?

Answer (score 3):

As the iPhone system sounds are the property of Apple, I cannot help you find them. If you do, however, place ringtones on your SD card under `/ringtones` and other sounds like new mail notification under `/notifications`. Go back into preferences and you should now be able to select these sounds.

Comment: Thanks Kyle! I will try to figure out how to transfer these from my iPhone :)

Answer (score 2):

[Zedge](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.zedge.android) is a pretty sweet ringtones/wallpaper app which I am sure includes said ringtones.